# Can SendGrid send mail to other domains?

Tags: wordpress, sendgrid

I'm using the SendGrid plugin on my Wordpress website to send transactional emails. I'm using a form and want to send the form submission to an email other than my domain. For some reason, I'm not receiving that email.  However, if I change the address on the form to the same address SendGrid sends from, it arrives instantly.  It makes no sense because SendGrid sends woocommerce order notifications to customers and they receive them. Why wouldn't it send this form submission?

Answer (score 1):

This should be obvious, but **have you checked your SPAM folder?**

You need to configure SPF and DKIM for your domain in order to ensure email delivery. SPF helps the receiver to verify the authenticity of email (where or not it's forged). I think SPF is not configured/misconfigured for your domain.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can send mail to any domain, only need to do correct smtp setting with correct credential. Send-grid sends mail to any domain.